# CLFloor returning nil in iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, ios8

So I am trying to get CLFloor in Core Location to give me data instead of returning nil in Swift, but I have not been able to. I have tried my own code and the following from NSHipster:

```
import CoreLocation

class LocationManagerDelegate: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: AnyObject[]!) {
        let location: CLLocation? = locations[0] as? CLLocation
        if let floor: CLFloor? = location?.floor {
            println("Current Floor: \(floor?.level)")
        }
    }
}

let manager = CLLocationManager()
manager.delegate = LocationManagerDelegate()
manager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Does anybody know how to make this work on a device or in the simulator, I'm sure the answer would benefit a lot of people. If anyone knows of any good resources on this or CLVisit, that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

based on these 2 links from Apple's website

[CLFloor Ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLFloor_class/index.html)

[CLLoaction Class Ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocation/floor)

> Discussion
>   If floor information is not available for the current location, the value of this property is nil.

I'm not expert in swift but i think
returns nil possibly means that there is no floor information at that location.

Comment: That makes sense. Does floor info have to be set through some other source?

Comment: I guess its automatic based on GPS location.
and altitude maybe

Answer (score 11):

As far as I understand what was said in [WWDC session 708 - Taking Core Location Indoors](http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/708), You need to **manually register** and set up the particular venue on the new Apple's [Maps Connect](https://mapsconnect.apple.com) page in order to get the floor information in iOS.

Therefore, it seems there is no way that the floor info is provided automatically (e.g. based altitude information from on GPS) for an arbitrary venue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think iOS will magically tell you the floor level from what I understand https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=708. You need to somehow get that number in another way. E.g. you may capture some iBeacon signal and from that download the floor level number, or swipe on your screen to find the correct floor map you are on?